# backurls mercadopago no funcionan en mobile

Tags: php, laravel, mercadopago

Tengo mi smartcheckout funcionando en desktop pero al hacer el pago boton de volver al sition no funciona, no me redirige pero si me cobra el pago

```php
MercadoPago\SDK::setAccessToken(' MI KEY ');

                    // Crea un objeto de preferencia
                    $preference = new MercadoPago\Preference();
                    $preference->back_urls = array(
                        "success" => "https://www.sabordecasa.com.ar/procesar-pago-sinenvio",
                        "failure" => "https://www.sabordecasa.com.ar",
                        "pending" => "https://www.sabordecasa.com.ar"
                    );
                    $preference->auto_return = "approved";
                    // Crea un ítem en la preferencia
                    $item = new MercadoPago\Item();
                    $item->title = 'Mi libro';
                    $item->quantity = 1;
                    $item->unit_price = $precio;
                    $preference->items = array($item);
                    $preference->save();
```

Comment: ya probaste con auto_return = "all" ?

Comment: Tampoco funcionan en desktop. Es decir, ni back_urls ni auto_return tienem efecto alguno.

Answer (score 2):

Este problema lo tuve tambien, el modo de resolverlo fue generar el boton con un href y colocando como link el valor generado por el objeto preference

Ejemplo:

```
<a href="<?php echo $preference->init_point; ?>">Pay</a>
```

Mas info en:
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/v1/receive-payments/

Answer (score 1):

Estoy intentando resolver el mismo problema con Smartcheckout y noté que al cerrar el modal de la pasarela de pago cuando termina, mas allá de no redireccionar a las `back_url`, la ruta a la que retorna es la que se indica en el action del form que se indica en el snippet de [la documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.uy/developers/es/guides/payments/web-payment-checkout/integration/), y con parámetros que contienen información sobre el estado del pago.

```
<form action="/procesar-pago" method="POST">
  <script
   src="https://www.mercadopago.com.uy/integrations/v1/web-payment-checkout.js"
   data-preference-id="<%= @preference_id %>">
  </script>
</form>
```

Los parámetros que se envían al endpoint especificado en el action del form son:

```
preference_id = ...
&collection_status=in_process
&external_reference=null
&payment_type=credit_card
&merchant_order_id= ...
&site_id=MLU
&processing_mode=aggregator
&merchant_account_id=null
&payment_id= ...
&payment_status=in_process
&payment_status_detail=pending_contingency
&merchant_order_id= ...
&processing_mode=aggregator
&merchant_account_id= ...
```

A mi me funcionó implementar un endpoint, cuya ruta es la que especifico en el action del form, que procesa estos parámetros y redirecciona a las urls que corresponden en cada caso.